# Integrability of the Fourier transform in Sobolev space

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

I believe that the statement below is a standard fact but I haven't figured out yet:

> Suppose $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ has integrable partial derivatives of order $n+1$ and $D^{\alpha}f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ for all multiindex with $|\alpha|\le n+1$ (here $D^{\alpha}$ is the mixed partial derivative). Prove that the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ is in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

Does anyone know the proof or a reference for this statement?

Comment: So $\hat{f}(1+\sum_k |\xi_k|^{n+1})$ is bounded, where $1/(1+\sum_k |\xi_k|^{n+1}) \in L^1(R^n)$

Comment: @reuns: My attempt: By Cauchy - Schwarz inequality, $\left(\int |\hat{f}(\xi)|\right)^2\le \int 1/(1+|\xi|^{n+1})^{2}\int (1+|\xi|^{n+1})^{2}\hat{f}(\xi)^{2}$ and the last integral is equal to $\sum_{\alpha\le n+1} \hat{D^{\alpha}f}(\xi)$. Am I right?

Comment: Who said the last integral converges ? I'm saying $|\hat{f}(1+\sum_k |\xi_k|^{n+1})|\le C \implies \|\hat{f} \|_{L^1} \le C \|1/(1+\sum_k |\xi_k|^{n+1}) \|_{L^1}$. $C$ is obtained from the fact $\partial_{\xi_k}^{n+1} f \in L^1$ so its Fourier transform is bounded